# Hadoop DFSClient installation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I run Hadoop cluster and I'm interested to install one more machine with DFSClient only.

This machine (lets call it machine X) will not be a part of the cluster.

Machine X will run DFSClient and I should be able to see HDFS from it.

In order to install DFSClient, I copied Hadoop home directory from one of cluster's node to machine X (including .jar files and configuration).

Then I run:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

I get the local ROOT directory (not HDFS ROOT).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the content of the core-site.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Copy hdfs-site.xml and place in a folder under your local linux account home dir. Then ensure that your name node (default.fs.name) is pointing to the remote namenode. Then try `hadoop --config <your_config_folder> fs -ls /` where your_config_folder is where you placed your hdfs-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it should work if the following steps are done

- If you have copied the configuration files`(*.xml)` from the hadoop cluster.
- `HADOOP_HOME` set with the copied hadoop path.
- `Machine X` should have access to the cluster network